# Looping through HTML controls - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have some rows that runs on server and I want to make some of them bold according to some conditions. How can I loop through the controls. My rows seems like this:

```
<tr id="row1" runat="server"></tr>
<tr id="row2" runat="server"></tr>
<tr id="row3" runat="server"></tr>
```

Comment: if your using HTML table.. try with <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**Markup**

```
<table id="table1" runat="server">
    <tr id="row1" runat="server"><td>cell1</td></tr>
    <tr id="row2" runat="server"><td>cell2</td></tr>
    <tr id="row3" runat="server"><td>cell3</td></tr>    
</table>
```

**Code**

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

...

foreach (HtmlTableRow row in table1.Rows)
{
    row.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Repeater` to output the content. This has the ability to change rows based on `AlternatingItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplate`.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server" 
    onitemdatabound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" id="row" class="odd">
           <td><%# Container.DataItem %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" id="row" class="even">
           <td><%# Container.DataItem%></td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
       </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can also hook the [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) events and customize look and feel as the data is written.

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var data = e.Item.DataItem;
        var index = e.Item.ItemIndex;

        var row = e.Item.FindControl("row");

        // do something with row control
    }
}
```